# How to show the portion out of axes in a boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, clip

I'm making a boxplot with a fixed ylim.
Some of my data will result a box which out of the axes range.

I'd like to show the portion of the box out of the axes, but have no idea.

I know that the `ax.plot()` have a `clip_on` kwarg to show the line out of the axes range.

But `ax.boxplot()` seems have no a such kwarg.

I also tried to set `ax.set_clip_on(False)`, but it seems not work.
Is there any idea about this?

---

**Plus: *The following is an example to show what I want.***

We plot a normal box first:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(x=range(0, 10), positions=[0])
```

[image]

Then we set the ylim to make the whisker out of the axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(x=range(0, 10), positions=[0])
ax.set_ylim(2, 8)
```

[image]

**My question is how to show the whisker out of the axes in the second boxplot?**

Comment: there is one trick you can try: get another axis larger than you previous one and place on top of it, plot on that axis, then hide this large axis using ax.axis('off')...

Comment: @Jiadong Thanks for the comment! Yes, the method will be work at a single axes. While for my real case, There are 25×17 axes in a figure, and they are touched with each other. if set a larger axis, the box in some axes will be too small and hard to see.

Comment: you know you can plot multiple boxes in one axis, right? So you can only have a few axes, although I don't have your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to realize what I want, but not sure if it's the most effective one.

For each element of a boxplot, we can set the single element to avoid cliped.

For example, we can set `ax.boxplot(x=range(10), positions=[0], whiskerprops={'clip_on': False}, capprops={'clip_on': False})` to avoid the whisker and cap (the horizontal line at the end of the whisker) cliped.

If the box and median line are also cliped, the `medianprops={'clip_on': False}` and `boxprops={'clip_on': False}` kwargs are useful as well.